# woocommerce - how to change oocommerce_after_shop_loop_item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce problem
I write new action to change button " add to cart " in archive page.

Here is my code :

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'my_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

function my_woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
echo '
Add to cart <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
';
}
```

Button changed ! but problem is, when i press " Add to cart " button, it will be redirect to product details page...

I think i have to do something with : woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close

But I dont know how
So, can you help me ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because you have removed the action hook `'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart'` which adds essential information to the button code that enabled the ajax add-to-cart functionality on archive pages.
What you need to do is, remove your current code and use following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'woo_archive_page_cart_button_custom_class', 10, 2 );
function woo_archive_page_cart_button_custom_class($array, $product){
    return sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button icon-shopping-cart' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_page_cart_button_custom_text' );
function woo_archive_page_cart_button_custom_text() {
    return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

I guess you had two motives. One to change the button text on archive pages to read as "Add to Cart" instead of the default "Read more", and also to add shopping cart icon into the button next to the button text.

The first filter hook adds custom class `"icon-shopping-cart"` to the buttons default classes (which I guess will render the shopping cart icon). And the second filter hook changes the button text.

Hope this helps.